# WPBakery Page builder shows code on live page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, wpbakery

I came across a problem with the WPBakery Page builder (I have V. 6.7.0) on the live page.

I use the theme Sway (v. 2.2) by Key-Design, and they both support each other, but out of the blue the output code started to show in the text block and live on page! What could cause this?

I have tried looking in every .php file in my WordPress folder, even in the theme styling, and I can't find an answer.

Here is an example what every text and title looks like:

[image: Screenshot of page showing non-parsed shortcodes]

Anyways, thank you for your time!

Comment: actually for better reference, I could just put the link for the website: https://perlux.dk/

Comment: What you're seeing on screen are shortcodes (most likely generated by WPBakery) that are not being parsed into actual content. My guess is that this may be a theme issue. Have you tried contacting the Key-Design team for assistance with this yet? If not then it might be a good idea to do so.

Comment: aww i see! thank you Sir ! I haven't contacted Key-Design yet, I just feared that I was the issue.

Comment: Short update ! I fixed it. For those who, have a similar problem Its just the Redux framework that was the issue. I had the newest version of Redux which is v. 4.3.19 - you will have to downgrade it to a 4.3.16 until Sway comes with a more compatible update.